# Is it possible to create a new jobject of a java listener in JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface, native

In Android Studio `MainActivity`, I write something like

```java
int itemA_num = 0;
int itemB_num = 0;

ABCListener mabclistener = new ABCListenter() {
    @Override
    public void onEventActivated(CustomResult result) {
        //do sth secret e.g.
        itemA_num ++;
    }
}

ABCobject mabcobject = (ABCobject) findviewById(R.id.abcobject1);
mabcobject.setListener(mabcListener);
```

I don't want people to decompile my APK and modify the code by amending the value or adding something like this:

```java
ABCListener mabclistener = new ABCListenter() {
    @Override
    public void onEventActivated(CustomResult result) {
        //do sth secret e.g.
        itemA_num += 10000; //possibly some general name read by those guys and modified as int1 +=10000;
        itemB_num += 500; //possibly some general name read by those guys and added this line int2 +=500;
    }
}
```

So I want to use JNI with Cmake.  Inside a .cpp file, I want to create the Class Object, `findviewById`, `setListener` and create the `ABCListener`.
I know using the format

```cpp
jclass cls = (jclass) env->FindClass("abc/def/GHI");
jmethodID mid = (jmethod) env->GetMethodID(cls, "methodname", "(xxxx)yyy");
jobject obj = (jobject) env->CallObjectMethod(cls, mid, params);
```

However, if I want to write code about `ABCListener` and make a `jobject` of it, I don't know how and where to tell the machine I am going to write some code relating to `@Override public void onEventActivated(CustomResult result) { ... }`. I also want to add some lines of code inside the response in JNI.

I have found a website "similar" to this question but it is from 2011 and about Runnable. https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2298550/overriding-interface-methods-via-jni
I don't know if it still works in 2021.

Comment: If your threat model already assumes people will modify your code, what is to stop them from replacing your native implementation with a Java one again?

Answer (score 1):

First, define a new class on the Java side:

```
class NativeABCListener implements ABCListener {
  @Override public native void onEventActivated(CustomResult result);
}
```

Next, create an instance of `NativeABCListener`, either in Java or in native code, and attach it to your `mabcobject`. You know how to do this so I will not repeat it.

On the native side, you simply define a C++ method with the appropriate name:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_package_NativeABCListener_onEventActivated(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject result) {
   ...
}
```

If you need multiple `ABCListeners` that do different things, you can choose to create multiple `NativeABCListener` classes (each with their own corresponding native function), or you can modify `NativeABCListener` to store a C++ function pointer in a Java `long` field. In the `..._onEventActivated` function you then extract the field from `thiz` and call it like a regular functino pointer.